# taking variable from parent to child and inserting it into dynamic text field

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to take a variable from the parent movieclip and use it in the child movieclip inside of a dynamic text field.

The variable has a value that is taken from a php file.

I'm completely lost at the moment and know that my code is probably completely wrong.

here it is:

**parent movieclip:**

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("../SC/FLA_cont-btn.php"));


function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
variables.sponny = data.sponny_name;
}
```

**Child movieclip:**

```
trace((parent as MovieClip).variables.sponny);

sponsor_name.text = +variables.sponny;
```

I get 2 errors using this code:

1120: Access of undefined property event.
1120: Access of undefined property variables.

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error 1:**

Its called `evt` here: `function onLoaded(evt:Event):void`

And here you are trying to inspect an `event`: `new URLVariables(event.target.data);`

**Error 2:**

Is `variables` a property of the parent movie clip? Then you should write:

```
trace((parent as MyMovieClipClass).variables.sponny);

sponsor_name.text += (parent as MyMovieClipClass).variables.sponny;
```

**Additional Tipp:**

If `sponsor_name` is a `TextField`, use `appendText(text)` instead of `+= text`.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. Where you say "Its called evt here:", are you saying i need to replace function onLoaded(evt:Event):void with evt? Thanks

Comment: I meant your function accepts a variable called `evt`. And later you are referring to that variable with the name `event`. The latter should then also be `evt`.

Comment: hey. i just tried your code and it now says 1120: Access of undefined property variables.sponny.

Comment: also, when i try your addiotional tip to use appendText(text) i get "1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:MovieClip to an unrelated type String." and "1119: Access of possibly undefined property variables through a reference with static type void."